# Entity Framework models and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create an MVC 6 project in Visual Studio with a partly angularjs v1.4.6 front end. I am using WebAPI in the mix for get and put to the Entity Framework code-first database.
The website is meant to allow the user to record a collection of movies, where the movie is located, what sort of media it is on and the details which are retrieved by looking up imdb through a REST $http call.
The Main Model looks like this.

```
namespace OurMovies.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MovieCollectionID { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public int MediaTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int MovieDetailID { get; set; }

        public virtual MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
        public virtual MovieCollection MovieCollection { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual MovieDetail MovieDetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

-

```
// GET: api/Movies
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies(int? collectionID)
        {
            return _repo.GetMovies(collectionID);
        }

// POST: api/Movies
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostMovie([FromBody] Movie movie)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Movie.Add(movie);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (MovieExists(movie.ID))
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetMovie", new { id = movie.ID }, movie);
        }
```

My problem is that the GET call for Movie does not fully expand the virtual members, e.g.

```
MediaType  {"ID":1 , "name": "DVD"}
Location   {"ID":1,"name":"Shelf 1"}
```

I end up with this:

GET http://localhost:43408/api/Movies

```
[
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "LocationID": 2,
    "MediaTypeID": 2,
    "MovieCollectionID": 1,
    "MovieDetailID": 1,
    "Title": "Sherlock Holmes",
    "MediaType": **null**,
    "MovieCollection": **null**,
    "Location": **null**,
    "MovieDetail": **null**
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "LocationID": 1,
    "MediaTypeID": 1,
    "MovieCollectionID": 1,
    "MovieDetailID": 2,
    "Title": "Jurassic Park",
    "MediaType": null,
    "MovieCollection": null,
    "Location": null,
    "MovieDetail": null
  }
```

This is a newbie question but I was wondering how I expand the foreign keys so that I can see data like MediaType.name in the angularjs page. My Main movie page looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--moviesView.html-->
<div class="row">
    <wait-cursor display-when="vm.isBusy"></wait-cursor>
    <h2>Movie Index</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Movie Title: <input type="text" class="fa-search" ng-model="searchString"></p>
        <p>
            <a ng-href="#/create">Add Movie to Collection - {{movies[0].collection.name}}</a>
        </p>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
            <tr><th>Movie Title</th><th>Movie Location</th><th>Media Type</th><th></th></tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter: searchString">
                <td ng-bind="movie.ID" hidden>
                     {{movie.ID}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a ng-href="#/show/{{movie.ID}}">{{movie.Title}}</a>
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="movie.movieLocation.name">                   
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="movie.mediaType.name">                   
                <td>
                    <a ng-href="#/edit/{{movie.ID}}">Edit</a> |
                    <a ng-href="#/show/{{movie.ID}}">Details</a> |
                    <a ng-href="#/delete/{{movie.ID}}">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using OData as a way to allow the client more control over queries? I've used OData with angular and it ended up being a very verasatile approach, although it might not suit your requirements.

Comment: Thankyou - I will checkout Odata. I still haven't got my LINQ query to deliver what I want.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of possibilities how to load related values. The easiest one is to update your Get method in repository to load related entities using .Include() in your linq statement.

```
var movies = context.Movies 
                   .Include(m => m.MediaType) 
                   .Include(m => m.Location)
                   .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == movieId);
```

One of the another methods (but not recommended) is to disable lazy loading in your DBcontext creation.

There are more options and you can find them on this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thanks...I have worked out that the Get method needs enhancement, and this solution will do nicely! I was having trouble wording the google query - almost spent the whole weekend on this issue - hence the post (no pun intended).